# USB Wifi driver installation Error: /lib/modules/4.14.98+/build: No such file or directory. Stop

Tags: wifi, usb

i need to  install the [USB wife `EDUP`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjPuPvW7ObiAhUNCewKHVmsA8gQjhx6BAgBEAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dx.com%2Fp%2Fedup-ep-n8508gs-mini-usb-2-0-150mbps-802-11-b-g-n-wi-fi-wireless-network-adapter-black-172021&psig=AOvVaw2rynSuF9jI6mEUNwFHS-ot&ust=1560528709274097) into my raspberry zero,

[image: USB wife <code>EDUP</code>]

so i try installing the CD container driver which is similar to [main GitHub container](https://github.com/CalielOfSeptem/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911) **_RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911_**  with this command:

`sudo make`

and i get this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/driver/linux_kernel2/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911 $ sudo make
make ARCH=armv6l CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.14.98+/build M=/home/pi/Desktop/driver/linux_kernel2/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.14.98+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:584: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

In my `/lib/modules/` folder i  have these folders:

```
4.14.98+  4.14.98-v7+  4.19.42+  4.19.42-v7+
```

so with `uname -r` i get :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/lib/modules $ uname -r
4.14.98+
```

but in `/lib/modules/4.14.98+` i dont have `build` folder!! `ls you can see here:

```
$ ls /lib/modules/4.14.98+
kernel         modules.alias.bin  modules.builtin.bin  modules.dep.bin  modules.order    modules.symbols
modules.alias  modules.builtin    modules.dep          modules.devname  modules.softdep  modules.symbols.bin
```

but i have this `build` folder in my `/lib/modules/`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/lib/modules $ find -name build
./4.19.42-v7+/build
./4.19.42+/build
```

my Question link in `rapberrypi.org`:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=242671&p=1479992#p1479992

So what can i do to solve this problem.

Comment: your question has nothing to do with RPi .... you should post here instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Answer (score 0):

based on https://github.com/lord2y/rtl8192eu-arm-linux-driver/issues/2 , do these commands:

```
#based of https://github.com/lord2y/rtl8192eu-arm-linux-driver/issues/2
sudo apt-get update  --fix-missing
 sudo apt-get install git raspberrypi-kernel-headers build-essential dkms
```

but still there is some problem which is asked here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525185/edup-wifi-instllation-in-reaspberry-pi-error